# How do I create an alias to Format-Table in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have a Powershell `Format-Table` string, something like:

```
ls | Format-Table Name, @{expression={$_.Length / 1024}; label='KB'}
```

I'm happy with the output I get from this, but I don't want to type it every time I use it. I'd like to be able to call it with a simple one-word command, something like:

```
ls | Format-KiloBytes
```

I gather I should be defining a function for this, since an alias can't specify the parameters. However, if I define something like:

```
function kilobytes {format-table Name, @{expression={$_.Length / 1024}; label='KB'}}
```

then it doesn't have any effect:

```
PS> ls | format-table Name, @{expression={$_.Length / 1024}; label='KB'}
   ... Produces the formatted output

PS> ls | kilobytes
   ... Produces output with unchanged formatting, the same as 'ls'
```

**Edit:** It appears I was confused. When experimenting, I'd already created an alias `kilobytes` that was aliased to `Format-Table`. I'd forgotten this, but this meant that creating a function `kilobytes` succeeded without any warning, but subsequently calling `kilobytes` wasn't calling the newly-created function but the existing alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you can try :

```
function kilobytes {$input | format-table Name, @{expression={$_.Length / 1024}; label='KB'}}
```

You can find the explanation of `$input` in [about_Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx). When you use a function in a pipeline, the objects piped to the function are assigned to the $input automatic variable.

Comment: That seemed to work. Can you expand on what the `$input` variable means? How does it get defined? Is it a magic variable that's auto-defined by PS, or is the name just an arbitrary placeholder?

Comment: I was writting it. But I'am looking for another solution. I try something with filter without success.

Comment: A filter is usually preferred because it supports streaming behavior.  $input is an automatic variable that stores all of the upstream output.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working Filter version:

```
filter kilobytes {$_ | select Name,@{expression={$_.Length / 1024}; label='KB'}}
```

Or:

```
filter kilobytes {[PSCustomObject]@{Name=$_.name;KB=$_.length/1024}}
```

Comment: Yes it works like this also, but I was hopping a more simple line with filter.

Comment: Added another version.  Not sure if that's what you had in mind or not.

Comment: Yes this is a brief solution.

Answer (score 0):

A proxy function provides a good way to bind one or more parameters while still supporting the original command in a natural way.  A search on Bing for "powershell proxy function" will give lots of good details.

Below is a proxy function that does exactly what you want.  You can see how you still have the Format-Table parameters like -AutoSize, but no -Property parameter as that has been hard coded.

A smarter version of this proxy might actually support adding additional properties to the hard coded ones.

```
function Format-Kilobytes
{
    [CmdletBinding(HelpUri='http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113303')]
    param(
        [switch]${AutoSize},
        [switch]${HideTableHeaders},
        [switch]${Wrap},
        [System.Object]${GroupBy},
        [string]${View},
        [switch]${ShowError},
        [switch]${DisplayError},
        [switch]${Force},
        [ValidateSet('CoreOnly','EnumOnly','Both')]
        [string]${Expand},
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [psobject]${InputObject})

begin
{
    try {
        $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Format-Table',
            [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
        $properties = "Name",@{expression={$_.Length / 1024}; label='KB'}
        $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters -Property $properties }
        $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
        $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}
process { try { $steppablePipeline.Process($_) } catch { throw } }
end { try { $steppablePipeline.End() } catch { throw } }
<#
.ForwardHelpTargetName Format-Table
.ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet
#>
}
```